# A morphism in $Hom (a,a)$ which is not the identity morphism

Tags: category-theory, functors, morphism

So, when defining a category, one is careful enough to define the identity of a object $a\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal C) $ as a particular element of the hom-class, $\text{id}_{a}\in\text{Hom}(a,a)$. That does seem natural, especially when one defines a functor. After all, it wouldn't really mean anything for a functor to preserve the identity morphism if the hom-class $\text{Hom}(a,a)$ only went around the identity.

So, yeah, I'm not relutant into accepting that. But I'm having trouble visualizing how could you even define a morphism from an object to itself that does not simply converge to the definition of an identity. I do suspect that this uncapability of mine may be me restricting my understanding to small categories.

So, how can you define a morphism in $\text{Hom}(a,a)$ without just going back to the definition of an identity? Because, once again, if the distinction is not made, I don't think the identity morphism preserved by a functor can make sense. Plus, the definition of a category to that extent, would also seem a little circular.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not following.  What does it mean for a morphism to "converge to the definition of the identity"?  Surely you can come up with examples for which $\text{Hom}(a,a)$ contains more than a single element.

Comment: Maybe "converge" was a bad term. Basically, what's in the hom-class $\text{Hom}(a,a)$ other than $\text{id}_a$ itself? Anything that you define via a mapping $f:a\to a$ is the usual definition of the identity mapping, and the hom-class consists of morphisms defined in that particular way.

Comment: In general, there are lots of morphisms between a fixed object and itself.  For $\mathbf {Sets}$ we are just looking at functions between a given set and itself.  If $S$ is the set $\{1,2\}$ then $\text{Hom(S,S)}$ has $4$ elements.

Comment: Aren't there plenty of functions $f: X \to X$ when $X$ is a set of cardinality more than 1?

Comment: Anything you see in category theory should make sense with sets.

Comment: Last thing:  the identity axiom puts restrictions on how ONE morphism from $\mathrm{Hom}(a,a)$ should behave, not *all* of them.

Comment: In a category, you only know about one element in $\mathrm{Hom}(a,a)$, the identity element, and there are objects for which that is the only morphism. So there is no abstract way, no formal category-theoretical way, to construct a non-identity morphism on an arbitrary object. But as others have pointed out, there are plenty of examples of objects $a$ with non-identity morphisms $a \to a$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is the category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are functions between sets with the usual composition. Then given a set $S \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$, an element of $\operatorname{Hom}(S, S)$ is just a function from $S$ to itself, and of course there are typically many such functions. (For example, if $S$ is a finite set of size $n$, then there are $n^n$ functions from $S$ to itself, only one of which is the identity function.)

Many examples are similar to the above. For a different sort of example, given a group $G$, we can define a category $\mathcal{C}$ as follows: there is only a single object (call it $\bullet$), and the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet, \bullet)$ are exactly the elements of $G$, with composition given by the group law in $G$. (This lets us think of every group as a category with one object in which all morphisms are invertible.)

Hopefully these two examples are enough to give you a sense of how this is possible. In general, because categories are such abstract, general objects, it's always a good idea to ground your understanding of category theory in concrete, familiar examples.